# Footer gets misplace on orientation Change in IOS 7 Safari while keyboard opened

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Hope you all are doing good.

Basically I am working on Dojo Mobile. The issue I am facing is when I open the keyboard by focusing input and then I Change the orientation from landscape to Portrait, My footer having tab bar gets misplaced (goes 100px up from bottom).

The one of the meta tag I am using is

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
```

I am facing this issue in IOS7 Safari browser. any help or Suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    dojox.mobile.resizeAll();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply tik27. I will let you know.